# Jenkins with Jenkinsfile Pipeline - Trigger Builds Remotely

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile setup for our CI/CD pipeline, and it runs through the pipeline on git actions like Pull Requests, Branch Creation, Tag Pushes, etc..

Prior to this setup, I was used to setting up Jenkins build jobs in the Jenkins UI. The advantage of this, was that I could setup dedicated build jobs that I could trigger remotely, and independently of git webhook actions. I could do a POST to the job endpoint with parameters to trigger various actions.

Documentation for this process would be referenced [here](https://www.toolsqa.com/jenkins/jenkins-build-jobs/) - see "Trigger Builds Remotely"

I could also hit the big button that says "Build", or "Build with Parameters" in the UI, which was super nice.

How would one do this with a Jenkinsfile?  Is this even possible to define build jobs in a pipeline definition within a Jenkinsfile? I.E. define functions / build jobs that have dedicated URLs that could be called on the Jenkins URL independent of webhook callbacks?

What's the best practice here?

Thanks for any tips, references, suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting with Multibranch pipelines. In general you get all the things you mentioned, but a little better. Because thhe paramteres can be defined within your `Jenkinsfile`. In short just do it like this:

1. Create a Jenkinsfile an check this into a Git Repository.
2. To create a Multibranch Pipeline: Click New Item on Jenkins home page.
3. Enter a name for your Pipeline, select Multibranch Pipeline and click OK.
4. Add a Branch Source (for example, Git) and enter the location of the repository.
5. Save the Multibranch Pipeline project.

A declarative Jenkinsfile can look like this:

```
    pipeline {
      agent any
      parameters {
        string(name: 'Greeting', defaultValue: 'Hello', description:  'How should I greet the world?')
      } 
      stages {
        stage('Example') {
          steps {
            echo "${params.Greeting} World!"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

A good tutorial with screenshhots can be found here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/

Comment: Could you please provide an example of something that would be defined in a Jenkinsfile after this is setup that accomplishes what the question is requesting?